# haproxy sni routing not working

Tags: haproxy

No matter what I try I can't get more than one server or backend to load. It's like it's ignoring the sni checks. I'm currently using haproxy version 2.6.2 on ubuntu server. My current code is:

```
defaults
  timeout client 30s
  timeout server 30s
  timeout connect 5s

frontend site_https
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }  
  default_backend back_https

backend back_https
  mode tcp
  acl a1_acl req_ssl_sni -i a.domain.com
  acl a1_acl req_ssl_sni -i b.domain.com
  acl a1_acl req_ssl_sni -i c.domain.com
  acl a2_acl req_ssl_sni -i d.domain.com
  use-server s1 if a1_acl
  use-server s2 if a2_acl
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server s1 192.168.0.1:443
  server s2 192.168.0.2:443
```

whatever I enter in the domain name results in server s2 loading. It's completing ignoring server s1. I've read through many tutorials and the haproxy docs but there must be something I'm just missing. Any help/suggestions would be very welcome.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out my haproxy setup was all fine. After more testing I noticed that if I closed my browser between trying to hit the different domains it would work. Then it made me think that it wasn't recognizing the change and it was my certificate that was the problem. I was using a wild card cert *.domain.com. Changed that to be two certs one for a.domain.com, b.domain.com and c.domain.com and then d.domain.com and it is all working perfectly fine now.

hopefully this will help someone else.